# Having trouble installing pdftotext on Windows

Tags: python, windows, pdftotext, poppler

I am trying to install pdftotext on windows via `pip install pdftotext`.  I am getting the following error:

```
pdftotext.cpp(3): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'poppler/cpp/poppler-document.h': No such file or directory.
error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Professional\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.36.32532\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
```

I've done the following:

1. Visual Studio 2022 C++ Build Tools are installed.
2. I've downloaded Poppler and unzipped it.
3. I've created system environment variables POPPLER_PATH (to point to where I unzipped the files), POPPLER_LIBRARY_PATH (where the .dlls are, e.g. Library\bin), POPPLER_INCLUDE_PATH (Library\include folder).
4. I've added Poppler's `bin` folder to the PATH environment variable
5. I've installed `pip install poppler-utils` (another question on SO recommended it)
6. I've checked the bitness of everything - it's all 64 bits.

Nothing has worked so far.  What am I missing?

P.S. Here is the [entire output](https://pastebin.com/eQ7vmSGB) of the command if it helps.